# How did i solve the error on view using laravel framework?

Tags: laravel

i change the folder in my public view because i dont want to confuse myself in the future when i tried to maintenance this website. But it's give me very weird error. I change the folder like this.

[image]

Of course because i change the name of the folder where is my view are bound to show. I need to change my code on controller too. here take a look

**Controller.php**

```
public function submitUpdateMeeting($id){
    $dataemployee =  EmployeeNik::all();
    $showideaupdateid = date("Yd") . rand(10,99);
    $showideaupdatetypeid = ShowIdeatypeUpdate::where('showideaupdatetype_isvisibled', '=', 1)- 
    >get();
    $dataparticipant = ShowIdeaParticipant::all();


    return view ('ProgramIdea.DetailProgramIdea.AddUpdate.updateidea', 
            compact('dataemployee', 'showideaupdatetypeid', 'id', 'showideaupdateid', 
            'dataparticipant'));
}
```

even tough i've already edited that part, i got an very frustating error (for me), here is the error on my website.

[image]

i tried any cache clear using this command `php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan route:clear`, `php artisan config:clear`, and using this one `php artisan view:clear`, i tried all i could.
but still no hope
it's just giving me an error
that's why i stumbled upon this asking question, help mee

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, when naming your folders use snake_case names instead of PascalCase or camelCase. Then, share your full folder structure for your problem, because i don't see last deep and previously folders.

If you are change views directory, update this on config/view.php and be sure use command: php artisan view:cache

Comment: i've already included a photo of my folder tough, on the first images.and i've already cleared the view chace too